# SQL to remove tags not found in an array:

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `item` table, a `tags` table and a `item_tagged` table.

I want to remove rows from the the database if an item is not found in an array.

For example:

```
$array = 'john', 'game', 'nintendo';
```

Item id 2 has the following tags in the database:

```
'john', 'game', 'wonderful'
```

So 'wonderful' should be removed from the database.

What would be the sql for this?

```
item: id, content

item_tagged: item_id, tag_id

tag: id, name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep only the tags in the array, this should do the job.

```
DELETE FROM item_tagged 
  WHERE item_id = 2 AND tag_id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM tag WHERE name IN (<<list your array contents here>>)
  )
;
```

Keep in mind this will not delete any orphaned tags, eg tags which are not assigned to any item.

Comment: Will this also remove the name from the tag table?

Comment: @jon*ie No, this will not delete unused tags. Thats another query: DELETE FROM tags WHERE tag_id NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM item_tagged WHERE item_id = id);

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM `item` WHERE `content` NOT IN ('.implode("','",  $array).');
```

Comment: I think jon*ie wants to delete tags, not items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using "tagmap" techniques. Exclusion methods vary depending on the complexity of your statement.

Check out http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html#toxi for Exclusion example.